Show more / show less in angular
<ng-container *ngFor="let item1 of errorItem.controls.errortype.value">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of notesLog.slice(0,showmoreless ? undefined : 3)">                                      
     <tr
        *ngIf=" 
        item.errortypegenid === item1.ErrorTypeGenId &&
        item.errortypegenid === errorItem?.controls?.myitemsArray.value[i].errortypegenid">
          <td>{{ item?.comment }}</td>
          <td [width]="120">{{ item?.Action }}</td>
          <td [width]="120">{{ item?.updatedby ? item.updatedby : item.createdby }}</td>
          <td [width]="120">
             {{(item?.UpdateDate ? item.UpdateDate : item.CreatedDate) | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
     </tr>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>

When I click on show more entire table is showing, when I click on show less no records are showing. when I click on show more only latest 3 records should be displayed. while clicking show less all records should be displayed

check if the below *ngIf condition is failing when the show less is implemented!
